# SQL OleDBCommand selecting Excel Columns

Tags: c#, sql, excel, oledb, oledbconnection

I'm using OleDBCommand to select some data in an Excel sheet I have. I have One column that has lists of data (column J) and every column after that either (columns K - AG) has a 1 or 0 depending on a relationship. So it's basically a graph plotted with 1 or 0. I want to use a SQL command to select every entry in column J where there is a 1 plotted in a column I choose. For example, say I want to look at the column J to K relationship. Then I would want to pull all data from J where columns J and K have a 1. 
I am unsure of how to specify columns in SQL. I have currently:

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Master$J0:J20] , connection);
```

I would need a WHERE clause after that to specify, where K0:K20 = '1' right? Or something like that. I can't get it.

Comment: This is not the way how stackoverflow community will give you answers. You need to -at least- try and fail, Check this page about your topic. I'm sure it will help you https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/getting-data-between-excel-and-sql-server-using-odbc--/

Comment: Ah well that link gave me answers so I guess they do.

Comment: The point is that the answers help us all, not only to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution:  Columns can be referenced by F1, F2, F3...FN. So in my case I would want for example:

```
SELECT F8 FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE F11 = '1'
```

Comment: A simple answer to a simple question. All other answers I saw were too complicated. +1 from me.