# How to update excel sheet using c#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have two Excel sheets.

This is the first sheet.
[image]

This is the second sheet
[image]

In the first sheet there is a column called Language and there is a similar column in the second sheet. So now I want Language data from the first sheet to the second sheet according to their ID.

Below is my Code.

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
string sql = null;

MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\consolidated.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");


MyConnection.Open();
myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
              
sql = "Update [second$]  set  [second$].[Language] =[first$].[Language]  where [first$].[ID]= [second$].[ID]  ";
myCommand.CommandText = sql;
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

MyConnection.Close();
```

**Getting below error :**

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters.

I'm not very skilled with SQL already, so my SQL syntax could be wrong too...but I'm not sure.

Comment: try using HDR=YES; in your connection string.

Comment: still same error coming

Comment: Try also setting IMEX=1; in your connection string beside HDR=YES; This error often appears when OleDb didn't load column headers properly from the first row in your worksheet. If that does not work, try refering to columns by the F1,F2,F3.. (those are default when the correct headers were not loaded) as is done here http://stackoverflow.com/a/24314010/891715

Comment: still same error.i think there is something wrong in my SQL query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best I could come up with :)

```
        var connectionStringBuilder = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
        connectionStringBuilder.DataSource = @"c:\dev\tmp\consolidated.xlsx";
        connectionStringBuilder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
        connectionStringBuilder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 12.0;");

        using (var connection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ToString()))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var updateCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
            updateCommand.CommandText = "update [second$] S inner join [first$] F on S.ID = F.ID set S.Language = F.Language";
            updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: What is 'S' here ?

Comment: Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'F.[Language] from [scada$] S JOIN [consolidated$] F on F.[ID]= S.[ID]'. , its giving error :(

Comment: See my updated answer, the syntax is slightly different

Comment: I am really happy to see you answer :) Thank you so much :)

Comment: Hello ,i have small doubt. how can i update sheet from diff workbook ? logic will remain same only sheet is in diff workbook.

Comment: in "otherfile.xlsx" i have to give file name of full path of file ? can u explain pls

Comment: it should be a full path

Comment: Its giving  Syntax error in UPDATE statement....and how it will read second  excel file without creating connection for it ?

Comment: Sorry, for posting the unconfirmed update. Looks like this cannot be done in a single update statement. I have now removed my update. I tried a different syntax which could have worked and got "You cannot edit this field because it resides in a linked Excel spreadsheet..." error. Looks like OleDB limitation